# IIF condition in SSRS and handling zeros

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iif

I've got a fairly complex formula in SSRS and for some reason it shows an error when it encounters a zero value, even though I'm handling zeros in my formula. Can anybody advise how to fix this issue?

=iif(datepart("h",Now())=6, iif(SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value) = 0, 0,((SUM(Fields!Revenue.Value) - SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value)) / SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value)))
,iif(SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value) = 0, 0,(SUM(Fields!Revenue.Value) / SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value))))

Comment: What error are you getting and what values are being used, are PYRevenue and Revenue both 0?
I'm using this query and don't get any errors.

`Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int, PYRevenue int, Revenue int )
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,6,7)
,(2,3,6)
,(3,0,0)
SELECT * FROM @YourTable`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread your formula until I indented it properly.  Even though you have a check for PYRevenue = 0, you need to also include another IIF() after both occurrences of "/", like so:

iif(
    SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value) = 0, 
    0,
    (
        (SUM(Fields!Revenue.Value) - SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value)
    ) / **IIF(SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value) = 0, 1, SUM(Fields!PYRevenue.Value))**
)

SSRS evaluates all the expressions so you have to handle the 0 value even if your parent logic prevents that block from being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the hurried answer... Doing this on my phone..

Even though your last expression will not be used if SUM(PYRevenue) is zero, it will still get evaluated and give a divide by zero error. 
2 ways to resolve. 
I personally use SWITCH instead of IIF for anything that is not simple.

Alternatively you need to check SUM(PYRevenue) on both side of your division. Pseudo code would be  `=IIF(SUM(PYRevenue)=0,0,SUM(Revenue)) / IIF(SUM(PYRevenue)=0, 1, SUM(PYRevenue))` So if sum PY is zero then do 0/1 else do revenue/pyrevenue

Comment: After I posted I saw Chris Hackett's updated answer, basically the same except you realy don't need to the outer IIF if you get both sides of the divisor correct..